# Touch event handling in Blackberry

Tags: events, blackberry, event-handling, touch

I try to implement simple touch event handling on Blackberry 9550 emulator, but it doesn't work. Actually, touchEvent never gets called, 'cos no text ever appears in the console. Also, I get an annoying "Full Menu" which appears on touching the screen.
Here's the code:

```
package mypackage;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.EventInjector.TouchEvent;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.VirtualKeyboard;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{   
public MyScreen()
{    
    super(NO_SYSTEM_MENU_ITEMS);
    getScreen().getVirtualKeyboard().setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE_FORCE);      
    add(new HandleTouch());

}

class HandleTouch extends Field {

    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(width, height);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg.png"), 0, 0);
    }

    public boolean isFocusable() { return true;}

    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
        switch( message.getEvent() ) {
        case TouchEvent.CLICK:
            System.out.println("----------------------------->CLICK");
            return true;
        case TouchEvent.DOWN:
            System.out.println("----------------------------->DOWN");
            return true;    
        case TouchEvent.MOVE:
            System.out.println("----------------------------->MOVE");
            return true;    
        }
        System.out.println("PRINT ME SOMETHING IN ANY CASE");
        return false;
    }

    public HandleTouch() {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1). First of all, with this code

```
protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(width, height);
}
```

you are actually setting a VERY large size of the field. This because the BB UI framework passes max available/possible dimentions to `layout(int width, int height)` so the field should use some part within the passed values. In this specific case the width will be the width of the display (360 px) and the height is the max possible height of the `VerticalFieldManager` (the one your are adding screen fields to, it is implicitly present in the screen's internals) (1073741823 px). So, finally this may result in a very large `Bitmap` object that is required with the field in order to be painted and you can get an uncaught error "Bitmap is too large" (I did on Storm 9530).

So, the `layout()` should use some relatively small values, e.g.:

```
protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(Math.min(width, 360), Math.min(height, 480));
}
```

2).

> Actually, touchEvent never gets called

Well, actually it does get called. To see that you should simply touch (versus click). Left button of the mouse simulates clicks (a sequence of `TouchEvent.DOWN` > `TouchEvent.CLICK` > `TouchEvent.UNCLICK` > `TouchEvent.UP`), right button simulates touches (a sequence of `TouchEvent.DOWN` > `TouchEvent.UP`).

3).

> Also, I get an annoying "Full Menu" which appears on touching the screen.

This is because your field does not consume `TouchEvent.UNCLICK` event. For instance, with this code your field will not show the popup:

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
    return true;
}
```

But, that is a bad solution for the popup. It is better to understand what really causes the popup. If `TouchEvent.UNCLICK` event is not consumed then BB UI framework calls `getContextMenu(int instance)` and `makeContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, int instance)` methods of the field. So in order to disable the popup (which is actually a `ContextMenu` created by the `getContextMenu(int instance)` you should override the `getContextMenu(int instance)` to be smth like this:

```
public ContextMenu getContextMenu(int instance) {
    // just in case check if a context menu is requested
    // in order not to disable other types of menu
    boolean isContextMenu = (Menu.INSTANCE_CONTEXT == instance);
    return isContextMenu ? null : super.getContextMenu(instance);
}
```

4). Finally I'd recommend to not change native/default behavior of `touchEvent(TouchEvent message)` method. You can just watch/log it, but don't change (always call its super version). This is because touch events handling is more complicated than it may look at first. It is very easy to get a tricky bug here. I do believe most programmers should not change the native behavior of `touchEvent(TouchEvent message)` unless they really want to create some custom UI component to work with touch gestures. Normally they just want to react on a click (to behave as a `ButtonField`), however for that you can simply override `navigationClick(int status, int time)` or `navigationUnclick(int status, int time)`. The BB UI framework will call those methods when user clicks your field on a touch screen.

Comment: Where can I find out what exactly TouchEvent.CLICK is, and when it would be appropriate to catch them?  I find the BB docs very unhelpful.

Comment: @Mike D: a starting point is API (as always). Check the http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/TouchEvent.html As to "when it would be appropriate to catch them" - it depends on what you do. In most cases you don't need to bother with such low level handling (see my post above).

Comment: Hi. I'm working with Blackberry Touch Event and I need to process the MOVE, UP, DOWN to move a carousel of images and the TouchEvent.CLICK to generate some specific action. My problem is that the touchEvent is being called several times. How can I prevent this? Because the behaviour is getting messed up. For example: when I just want the CLICK event, the UP,DOWN,MOVE and CLICK are being triggered one after the next.

Comment: @mariomunera: please ask a separate SO question on this.

Comment: @Arhimed: thanks, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818850/touch-event-blackberry-triggered-multiple-times

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add extra info to Arhimed's answer, since this seems to be a landing page for googling touch events...

My experiences are not to contradict him, but to add possible solutions for future readers. I am using BB OS 5.0. My experiences have been with the Storm simulator, and a Torch device. My app was originally written for OS 4.5, so it might be running in some sort of compatibility mode.

1) As explained in his point 4, a Touch Event gets passed along to a Navigation Click event, if `touchEvent(TouchEvent)` returns false. If `navigationClick(int, int)` returns false, this prompts the system to display a `ContextMenu`.

2) On my system, I could not find a method `getContextMenu(int)`. So I could not test his point 3. I presume this gets added in BB6 or later.

3) I did find `getContextMenu()` - i.e. it takes no parameters. I tried to override that method to return null.

The strange thing is that this method only gets called **after** the initial context menu popup is shown! The initial context menu popup (?) gets shown, with a button on it for "Full Menu". When that button is pressed, this method gets called, and can be used to populate the `MainMenu` that appears. ... strange...

However, it means that overriding that method did not solve my problem.

4) I was unable to get a solution by returning true in `touchEvent(TouchEvent)`. I agree that this would have been bad form (hack), but I have learnt to hack a lot on the BB platform. However, scrolling list fields need to have the touch event passed up, so that the scroll works.

5) Eventually I found something similar to the OP's problem with `TouchEvent.UNCLICK`. It has taken me 18 months to find the method `navigationUnClick(int, int)`. Similar to my point 1 above, an unhandled `UNCLICK` becomes a `navigationUnClick(int, int)` call, which can **also** lead to the context menu being shown.

So by adding similar logic to both `navigationClick(int, int)` & `navigationUnClick(int, int)`, I was able to get my lists & touches to interact nicely.

---

This is just supplemental info, that may add to the accepted anser.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Regarding the "I could not find a method getContextMenu(int)" - most likely I studied this on Storm 9530 4.7 simulator. However knowing what RIM is able to do I'll be not surprised they silently changed the API later in OS 5. So it looks like I investigated some sort of corner case, while actually there should be a better way to manage context menus.

Comment: I'm not sure which is "better"... with BB, I think we can agree that there are more than a few "corner cases" - which is why I wanted to add to this page. The more info on strange issues like this, the better.