# Touch Event Blackberry Triggered Multiple Times

Tags: blackberry, touch-event

I'm working with the Blackberry Touch Event and I need to process the `TouchEvent.MOVE`, `TouchEvent.UP` and `TouchEvent.DOWN` to move a carousel of images and the `TouchEvent.CLICK` to generate some specific action.

My problem is that the `touchEvent()` method is being called several times. How can I prevent this? Because the behaviour is getting all messed up.

For example: when I just want to capture the `TouchEvent.CLICK` event, the UP-DOWN-MOVE-CLICK are being triggered one after the next.

My code does the following:

```java
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {

    if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK) {

        //CHANGE THE CONTENT OF A FIELD

        return true;
    } else if ((message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.MOVE)
            || (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.UP)
            || (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.DOWN)) {

        //DELETE THE FIELD
                            //MOVE A CAROUSEL OF IMAGES
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void moverTouch(int dx) {
    //ADD THE FIELD PREVIOUSLY DELETED
}
```

As you can see, when the `CLICK` event is captured, I need to change the content of a field, but when the `MOVE` or `UP` or `DOWN` event is captured, I need to delete that `Field` from his manager, do some working with a carousel of images, and then re-add the field previously deleted.

The carousel moving part works fine, but when I try to capture JUST the `CLICK` event, and the others are being triggered as well, but the `moverTouch(`) function doesn't get triggered because there is no actual movement on the carousel of images, I end up with a deleted field that I need to update its content.

Comment: On all blackberry's other than the original storm 9500, CLICK and DOWN are synonymous and always occur together. Similarly, UNCLICK and UP always occur together. You should simply ignore UP and DOWN events since there the 9500 devices are totally extinct.

Answer (score 3):

At a glance:

I think you need to differentiate touch gestures (I believe you are "listening" for something like a swipe gesture to scroll the gallery image) from "normal" touch events (specifically you need to process `TouchEvent.CLICK` to apply "some specific action" to the clicked image).

To decide whether the `TouchEvent` represents a gesture there is a `TouchEvent.GESTURE` constant. Then it is possible to know what exactly `TouchGesture` it represents by calling `TouchEvent.getGesture()`.

Some sample code for touch gestures can be viewed [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Swipe_gestures_trackpad_1226851_11.jsp).